# SQL: Including a where statement that includes all data

Tags: sql, where-clause

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to have a where statement that includes all data.  I thought * might work but it doesn't seem to be.  For example

```
Proc SQL;
Create Table test
Select * from Teradata
(
Select
Field_1
From
Example
Where
Field_1 = *
```

So basically the results would show everything in field_1.  I know this seems like a pointless where statement but I am trying to do a loop that will create 2 different tables.  So the first table would have a filter like field_1 = '1' but then the second table I would want all field_1 of field_1 so Field_1="all Data"

Does anyone know what I can do here?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why you need a `WHERE` clause at all. That being said, your syntax seems to be all over the place. You have a random subquery without a `FROM` just hanging on to the end of a `SELECT` query. Please clarify your issue or desired result.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table_name

Comment: Sorry it was just supposed to be an example.  So for this example I wouldn't need the where statement, but I am looping through the code to create 2 different tables.  In the first table I would have Field_1 = 'Field' and then in the second table I want all data so the where would have to be Field_1= "all data".  Does that make sense?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using Ultra Edit.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: No a DBMS is a database manager, like mysql, postgres, mssql etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Select *
From example_table
Where 1 = 1
```